# how to bind async method in PropertyChangedCallback of dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I need to call the async method from PropertyChangedCallback of a dependency property.

My dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SetTextProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("SetText",
typeof(string),
typeof(UserControl1),
new PropertyMetadata("",
new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged)));
    private async Task OnSetTextChanged()
    {
        //// My implementations.
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? What error do you get? You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @iSpain17 It shows the wrong return type error.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is incorrect. `PropertyChangedCallback`'s constructor needs a delegate with return type of `void` and requires two parameters:

```
public delegate void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

You can mark your callback as async, but it has to be `async void` and needs two parameters as input (even if you don't use these parameters at all):

```
private async void OnSetTextChanged(DependencyObject d, 
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await SomeMethod();
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I need to return Task instead of void

Comment: That is not possible. The argument requires a PropertyChangedCallback, and you can see the signature for that callback above. Or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.propertychangedcallback
Why do you need to return a Task?

Comment: Are there any other ways to bind the async method with dependency property? I need to call an async method via dependency property.

Comment: You can call the async method inside the callback, with await MethodName()

Comment: yes. But we have configured our source with some code checking gateways, it shows error like 'return task instead of void'. So only am asking.

Comment: `async void` methods are asynchronous and were added to C# specifically to be used as event handler methods. Add a code checking rule for this.

Comment: When I working like that it shows the following rule violation. https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/async-await/RSPEC-3168

Comment: It is just a warning. And even Microsoft says that async void methods should not be used UNLESS it is an async event handler, which is the case for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: SonarSource seems to be faulty here: it even says at the bottom *Event handlers, i.e. methods with two arguments, first one matching object sender and the second being or inheriting from EventArgs, are ignored.*, which is true for this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MytextDependencyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(TestClass), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallbackAsync));

    private static async void PropertyChangedCallbackAsync(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await someMethod();
    }
```

**static async void**, did the trick for me.